# Kubernetes Services not reachable after introducing Ingress with nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have some services with external IP addresses in Kubernetes that I was able to reach by navigating to the IP. I then configured an Ingress with a nginx Ingress-Controller:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

I can now reach the service over the static IP of the Ingress, as expected. But can no longer reach the service directly over its external IP, nor any other services in k8s... why can't I reach the services with Ingress configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ingress Controller needs to be configured to allow access via its `rules`. See the documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/